# Centering a Relative Div

Tags: html, css

Tried a few things(margin-auto, text align:center etc) to centre this relative div - which is the header in my responsive layout with no luck. Any other ways to try?

The problem is keeping it centered as the page expands/contracts

Its CSS properties are

```
#header {
    height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: The width is set to `100%`. It's always centered. Also, having `padding-left` or `padding-right` on a div with 100% width will make it wider than it's container.

Comment: could you share the html please!

Answer (score 0):

How can a div appear visually centered when it's 100% width of its parent?

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6332ytc/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    height: 300px;
}
.inner {
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Getting a bit of joy using and editing     margin: 0px 0 0 -50%;
    left: 50%;